# Flutter offset in Draggable.onDragUpdate different than DragTarget's

Tags: flutter

I have a `Draggable` widget and a `DragTarget` that accepts that widget:

```
Draggable(
  child: someText,
  childWhenDragging: Container(),
  feedback: Material(
    child: someText,
    color: Colors.transparent,
  ),
  maxSimultaneousDrags: 1,
  onDragUpdate: FUNCTION_1,
)
...
DragTarget(
  onAcceptWithDetails: FUNCTION_2,
  onWillAccept: (data) => true,
)
```

The confusing thing is, FUNCTION_1 receives my dragging finger's coordinate (in  `DragUpdateDetails.globalPosition`), but FUNCTION_2 receives the coordinate of the `someText` (in `DragTargetDetails.offset`).

How do I make FUNCTION_1 receive `someText`'s coordinate (as it is dragged) instead?